# How to switch user profiles with passportJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am creating a "masquerade" admin log in system where admins can log into different user's accounts.
I am using a passport/express authentication system. I am trying to figure out a way to sign into another user's account while they are signed in as an admin.
My current strategy is to modify the req.user object and switch the password and username on the user object, then forward the modified user object to the login function in order to sign in as a different user. Is this possible or should I find a different way about this?

Thank you!

Comment: which strategy are you using?

Comment: local strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using express-session.When you are serializing user, what happens is that express-session put your user info into your session.You can change the info that you re putting in your session. You might add something like "currentAccount" if the user is admin. If admin changes to a user account, you may also create a new session with a new account or you might looking for a cookie/session manupilation library and change info in the current session. With deserializing, you can reach session info in your req.session.passport and your currentAccount info will be also in req.session.passport

Comment: I am using cookie-session, but this is works, thank you so much! I can just reach in and change the user id in req.session.passport and I am in a different account! Beautiful!